# Cannot make regular expression work in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

For some reason I cannot make regular expressions work for multiline string. It works fine on a web

I have a text like this:

```
    First Line //remove leading spaces
Second Line //nothing to remove
  Third Line //remove leading spaces
Fourth Line
should be 1 line //remove leading spaces and new line next char is not a capital letter

 Fifth line //remove leading spaces, keep new line between the two sentences
```

I'm trying to use this regex

```
^ +|\b\n\b
```

It works almost fine (except it removes more new line than needed)  in online regex editors such as http://rubular.com/r/u4Ao5oqeBi

But it only removes the leading spaces from the first line
This is my code:

```
        NSString *myText = @"    First Line (remove leading spaces\nSecond Line (nothing to remove\n  Third Line (remove leading spaces\n Fourth Line\nshould be 1 line (remove leading spaces and new line next char is not a capital letter\n\n Fifth line (remove leading spaces, keep new line between the two sentences";
        NSLog(myText);

        NSString *resultText = [myText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"^ +|\\b\\n\\b"
                                                                 withString: @""
                                                                    options: NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                                      range: NSMakeRange(0, myText.length)];

        NSLog(resultText);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because you are using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` with a regex string in the `target` argument instead of the input string. It does not accept regular expressions. See the [Foundation Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:) help on this function.

You can use the following code to remove all leading spaces:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *myText = @"    First Line (remove leading spaces\nSecond Line (nothing to remove\n  Third Line (remove leading spaces\n Fourth Line\nshould be 1 line (remove leading spaces and new line next char is not a capital letter\n\n Fifth line (remove leading spaces, keep new line between the two sentences";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^ +" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:myText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myText length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

I am using `NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines` option to make `^` match the beginning of a line, not the beginning of the entire string (see this [Regular Expressions Metacharacters](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html) table).
Output:

```
First Line (remove leading spaces                                                                                                                                                                                     
Second Line (nothing to remove                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Third Line (remove leading spaces                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Fourth Line                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
should be 1 line (remove leading spaces and new line next char is not a capital letter                                                                                                                                                                 

Fifth line (remove leading spaces, keep new line between the two sentences
```